# exc_bad_access Code=2, address=0x38 at the bottom of a function

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access

This is pretty straight forward.  I am trying to execute a function that triggers the pre-filling of data.  However at the end of the function it dies.  I am executing all of this within the AppDelegate file.

```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let initialize = Initialize()

    // Check to see if the application ID exists
    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("appId") == nil ){
        // Refresh the info
        self.preload()
        println("Data Preload Completed")

    } else {
        // running anyways to trigger the error. 
        self.preload()
        println("Data Already Preloaded")
    }

    return true
}


func preload()->Bool {

    // Preload static data for the app.
    var conditions = Conditions()
    conditions.preloadData()

    var imageTypes = ImageTypes()
    imageTypes.preloadData()

    var propertyTypes = PropertyTypes()
    propertyTypes.preloadData()


    //Save the appId 58AEF58E-2794-4F60-B0A6-0FAB4A943811
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("58AEF58E-2794-4F60-B0A6-0FAB4A943811", forKey: "appId")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


    println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation())

    return true

}
```

Comment: Please post a stack trace. Se we can see where exactly it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this "The" answer to the issue, but I had to delete all of the Simulator profiles, and for each device hit [iOS Simulator].[Reset Content & Settings] and then hit the "Reset" button to confirm.  I suspect that somewhere along the way I corrupted the plist file that NSUserDefaults connects to.